# non vanishing of a bivariable polynomial

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Let $P(X,Y)$ be a non zero polynomial of $\mathbb C[X,Y]$. Let $\{(x_i,y_i)\in\mathbb C^2\mid i\in\mathbb N\}$ be an infinite subset of $\mathbb C^2$ with the property that $x_i\ne x_j$ if $i\ne j$. Does there exist an index $i_0\in \mathbb N$ such that there exists $n_0\in\mathbb N$ with the property that $P(x^n_{i_0},y^n_{i_0})\ne0$ for every integer $n\ge n_0$?

Thanks in advance for any answer or hint.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, we can drop the subscripts and simply ask whether there exists $(x, y) \in \mathbf{C}^2$ with $P(x^n, y^n) \neq 0$ all but a finite number of positive integers $n$?

Comment: I want the $(x,y)$ to be in a given set. I can not choose the $(x,y)$ anywhere in $\mathbb C^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer appears to be "no". As a counter example we can pick polynomial and sequence for which no such $n_0$ is possible. Let $P(x,y)=xy$ and let $(x_i,y_i)=(i,0)$. Then, $x_i\neq x_j$ for all $i\neq j$. Likewise, for any $i_0$, I will never be able to find an $n_0$ where the sequence is non-zero, since the entire sequence is always $0$. Namely, $$P(x_{i_0}^n,y_{i_0}^n)=x_{i_0}^n y_{i_0}^n=i_0^n\cdot 0^n = 0$$

Comment: Thanks for this terrible counter-example. What about if in addition i add the hypothesis that for every $i\ne j$, $y_i\ne y_j$.

Comment: Maybe try, $P(x,y)=x(y-1)$ and the sequence $(x_i,y_i)=(i,1)$.

Comment: Umm I do not understand this counter-example. In this one, all the $y_i $ are equal.

Comment: Ah yes, good point. Lets try, $P(x,y)=x-y$ and $(x_i,y_i)=(i,i)$.

Comment: OK! Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem. In general, multi-variate polynomials don't have individual isolated zeros (like 1 variable polynomials), they have zero-curves. Hence, there are normally many many many sequences of all zero values.